# how to fit a wide image in bootstrap thumbnail?

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, css, thumbnails, positioning

I have a four column row(col-md-3) row. Each column has a thumbnail of width-220px and height-360px.How can I fill/cover the thumbnail div with  images of different resolution(such as: 1920X1080px or 2480 X 3508 px)  ?

I have tried this:

```
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img  src="images/highres.jpg" alt="Nosmoking image">

        </div><!----End of thumbnail-->

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
           img{
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    .thumbnail{
        height: 360px;
        width: 220px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

I have used an image of 1920X1080px (wide) and it's just filling the half of the thumbnail.what i want is to keep the aspect ratio and cover the thumbnail. what is the simplest solution?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, there are some solutions, you can add different classes to each `.thumbnail` and add background image for each `.thumbnail` using CSS, but for now and for your current code, you can add this CSS and can resolve your problem:

```
.thumbnail > img{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to keep the aspect ratio, I suggest adding suitable classes to your  `.thumbnail` HTML element, then add the image using CSS background.

imagine this:

*HTML:*

```
<div class="thumbnail thumbnail-1"></div>
<div class="thumbnail thumbnail-3"></div>
<div class="thumbnail thumbnail-4"></div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.thumbnail {
  background-size:cover;
  backgrond-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.thumbnail-1{
  background-image:url("image1.jpg")
}

.thumbnail-2{
  background-image:url("image2.jpg")
}

.thumbnail-3{
  background-image:url("image3.jpg")
}
```

Comment: if I give the height: 100% then the image get stretched.But it should keep the aspect ratio as well as cover the entire thumbnail.

Comment: @Sharecorn No problemo, Glad that worked, If that worked maybe you should accept this question as the correct answer. Thanks